# How to get custom post types to play nice with schema.org (aka how to wrap the contents in the schema.org markup)?

Tags: custom-post-types

Building a Culinary site with a Custom Post Type like "Recipes". I'm fixing to wrap the content of the said post type in [schema.org's recipe microformat](http://schema.org/Recipe).

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

The link has given you example HTML:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Recipe">
  <span itemprop="name">Mom's World Famous Banana Bread</span>
  By <span itemprop="author">John Smith</span>,
  <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2009-05-08">May 8, 2009
  <img itemprop="image" src="bananabread.jpg" />

  <span itemprop="description">This classic banana bread recipe comes
  from my mom -- the walnuts add a nice texture and flavor to the banana
  bread.</span>

  Prep Time: <meta itemprop="prepTime" content="PT15M">15 minutes
  Cook time: <meta itemprop="cookTime" content="PT1H">1 hour
  Yield: <span itemprop="recipeYield">1 loaf</span>

  <div itemprop="nutrition"
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NutritionInformation">
    Nutrition facts:
    <span itemprop="calories">240 calories</span>,
    <span itemprop="fatContent">9 grams fat</span>
  </div>

  Ingredients:
  - <span itemprop="ingredients">3 or 4 ripe bananas, smashed</span>
  - <span itemprop="ingredients">1 egg</span>
  - <span itemprop="ingredients">3/4 cup of sugar</span>
  ...

  Instructions:
  <span itemprop="recipeInstructions">
  Preheat the oven to 350 degrees. Mix in the ingredients in a bowl. Add
  the flour last. Pour the mixture into a loaf pan and bake for one hour.
  </span>

  140 comments:
  <meta itemprop="interactionCount" content="UserComments:140" />
  From Janel, May 5 -- thank you, great recipe!
  ...
</div>
```

What you need to do is create the meta fields to collect the additional information to each post/recipe.

Then create a template that shows this information in a template similar to above. You would use single-{CPT_Slug}.php file for your CPT/Recipe page.

Info on custom fields: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields